# Cant add external js library in laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm

I want to use bs treeview.js library in my laravel project and i don't know how to do it. So far I have done the following:

1. `npm install --save bstreeview`
2. I added `require ('bstreeview');` in resources/js/app.js

When I try to compile it with `npm run dev` I get the

> ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> './bstreeview' in (...)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the same effect can't compile

Comment: Please be precise i'am not an expert, and i think i do follow it.

Answer (score 2):

i have check this package there is not `index.js`

so you can't import directly you can include file like this

```js
import 'bstreeview/dist/js/bstreeview.min.js';
```

---

`require ('bstreeview');`   it's means node is looking for `index.js` insde

`node_module/bstreeview/index.js` but in this package it is not there so u need to manually import like above mentioned

---

for
**jquery**

run `npm i jquery`

and inside `bootstrap.js` add this

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Doesn't matter in both cases installation and compilation looks the same

Comment: OK it compile with import 'bstreeview/dist/js/bstreeview.min.js'; but i've got jQuery is not defined error. All my js is write with jquery so i dont understand why i've got this error?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7 my bootstrap.js already have that line